# Overloading the + operator with a single-linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading

For my homework assignment I have to create an int Linked List. I have the copy constructor and assignment operator overloaded, but can seem to get the + operator overloaded. I have a defined destructor that clears the list.

```
List List::operator+(const List &add)
{
     List result;
     result += *this;
     result += add;
     return result;
}
```

The += is working. Also, when I do something like the following:
    List list3 = list1 + list2;
It works. It seems that the destructor is called right before it returns, so I get nothing for List3 if I do

```
List list3;    
list3 = list1 + list2;
```

Here is the copy constructor, assignment overload, and += overload

```
List& List::operator=(const List &assign)
{
    Node *traverse = assign.head;
    int x;
    int *passX = &x;
    while (traverse != nullptr)
    {
        x = traverse->getItem();
        this->Insert(passX);
        traverse = traverse->getNext();
    }
    return *this;
}

List342& List342::operator+=(const List342 &add)
{
    Node *traverse = add.head;
    int x;
    int *passX = &x;
    while (traverse != nullptr)
    {
        x = traverse->getItem();
        this->Insert(passX);
        traverse = traverse->getNext();
    }
    return *this;
}

List342::List342(const List342 &copy)
{
    *this = copy;
}

struct Node
    {
        int item;
        Node *next = nullptr;
        int getItem() const;
        Node* getNext() const;
        void setItem(const int &val);
        void setNext(Node* nodePtr);
    };
    Node *head;
    int itemCount;
```

The last portion is the struct for the node, and the two variables that the any object of this class will have.

Thanks

Comment: Do you obey [the rule of three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)? Do actually copy *the list* or just the pointer(s)?

Comment: post code which reproduces the problem...

Comment: The `+` looks fine. If copy construction works, the problem is in the assignment operator.

Comment: Show `operator=` and `operator+=` and copy-constructor and the class definition at least

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I did indeed copy the list

Comment: @KarolyHorvath sorry about that, just made the edit

Comment: you assignment operator appends, instead of overwrites.

Comment: we still need a MCVE to solve this. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm a little worried about your use of a pointer to a local variable in the call to the `Insert` function in you operator functions.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to figure this out

```
List& List::operator+(const List &add)
{
    List *result = new List;
    *result = *this;
    *result += add;
     return result;
}
```

My destructor was clearing the list before its return... Allocating space in the heap prevents the destructor from doing this.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: this is bug hiding, not the actual problem. I suspect it is in one of those functions you haven't showed, maybe List::List() or List::Insert()

Answer (score -1):

Good job implementing operator+ as a function of operator+=. However, you should declare both LHS and RHS const when overloading operator +.

```
const List List::operator+(const List &add) const
{
     List result;
     result += *this;
     result += add;
     return result;
}
```

The first const means that the function returns a const List, so you can't:

```
List A, B, C;
A + B = C;
```

The second one means that the function doesn't modify its' member variables, so you can trust that A+B doesn't modify A.

Assuming the default constructor is an empty list and your class doesn't use pointers, try declaring const correctly. Const variables scope differently than non-const. If your class uses pointers, make sure you're actually copying the relevant memory, not just the memory addresses.

Comment: Not sure I follow why the result should be const. For example `l3.Splice(l1+l2)`

Comment: Returning const is a bad idea; it prevents moves, among other things. If you want to prevent `A + B = C;`, the proper solution is to apply a *ref-qualifier* to `operator=`.

Comment: the result should be const because `A + B` should never be a lhs value.

is `l3.Splice(l1+l2)l3.Splice(l1+l2)` supposed to modify `l1` or `l2`? it's ambiguous code and generally awful style. if you want to use rhs values in a function call, declare them const...

Comment: If it's const, then `C = A + B;` must make an unnecessary copy from the temporary returned by `operator+`, instead of performing a move assignment.